# Laravel - Eloquent override get method when using where

Tags: laravel, eloquent, overriding

I override eloquent `get()` method in one of my models `OrderStatus`

```
public static function get()
{
    return "hit";
}
```

when I call it without where it's working fine

```
>>> $order_statuses = OrderStatus::get();
=> "hit"
```

But when I call it with `where` it uses the `parent` get method again:

```
>>> $order_statuses = OrderStatus::where('order_id', 24)->get();
=> Wilgucki\Csv\CsvCollection {#4434
      all: [],
   }
```

Is there a way to override it anyway?

Comment: But why do you wont to overwrite `->get()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that by overriding the `get()` method inside the query builder in `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`, an example of this override is provided in this [medium post](https://medium.com/@justin.park001/laravel-techniques-extending-the-query-builder-2f4aca7956a2). But in your case it seems you want to override it only when used against the `OrderStatuses` model.

The good news is that the `Builder` class has a [reference to the table](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html):

```
/**
 * The table which the query is targeting.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $from;
```

it is set here:

```
/**
 * Set the table which the query is targeting.
 *
 * @param  string  $table
 * @return $this
 */
public function from($table)
{
    $this->from = $table;

    return $this;
}
```

so you can do something like this:

```
namespace App\Override;
class QueryBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {
    //@Override
    public function get($columns = ['*']) {            
        if ($this->from == 'OrderStatus') {
           // customize the call
        } else {
            //Return default
            return parent::get($columns);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` function is not defined on the **Model** class but it is called as a *dynamic method* on the Eloquent **QueryBuilder**, that is is handled by calling on the **Model** class this function:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
```

At the end when you call the `get()` function on **Model** you are instead calling it dynamically on the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class.

So you can't really override the chainable method `get()` on a class derived from **Model** without messing up things.