# How to get all Users with a specific Role from another Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, roles

I have a User Model with 3 roles(['student','admin','teacher']) using spatie/larevel-permission
I want to be able to create a Model like Student, Admin, Teacher, that will return the users with that roles only.
EG.
I want to create a Student Model to only return All users with student role.

so i can perform queries like.  Student::get() etc.

Please how can i achieve this?

I created a model Student  and i use the protected $table='users' but i dont know how to make it return only Users with student roles

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is even possible using Laravel native accent and This is not **good practice** because this **approach** is not expandable. Imagine in the future for some reason you need to add another role to your application and you have to create another Model and do the same stuff again and if this continues then you are going to face a lot of Models which they all do the same.
The idea of `Model` is to represent data structure of a table.
I suggest using relations & Service classes instead of this approach which is neat.

```
namespace App\Services;

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

class GetAdminsService
{
    public function execute()
    {
        return Role::query()->where('name', 'administrator')->first()->users;
    }
}
```

and you can inject this class anywhere in your application and simply call the `execute()` method and get the data

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a `User` model, like this:

```
class User extends Model {
    //...
}
```

Now, let's create a `static` property, of the like of

```
protected static $mainRole = '';
```

so far, so good. Now, you can override Laravel methods, like in this example: [Laravel - Eloquent override get method when using where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891635/laravel-eloquent-override-get-method-when-using-where). This is a method taken from the example, which is not yet your solution, but it's a good starting point for your thinking:

```
namespace App\Override;
class QueryBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {
    //@Override
    public function get($columns = ['*']) {            
        if ($this->from == 'OrderStatus') {
           // customize the call
        } else {
            //Return default
            return parent::get($columns);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need to do it differently and since I do not have a Laravel project in front of me, I will not provide you the exact source-code. However, you will need to somehow infer in this `get` what the calling model's `$mainRole` is and use this override for `Builder` at your `User` model. You may need to override further methods in order to achieve this goal and you may need to add some supportive fields or functions for your query builder. I did not do this in Laravel, but I did something very similar in CakePHP and the approach was to see what the base classes are and override some methods in this manner.

Now, if your `User` is already able to differentiate between the case when `$mainRole` is truey or not (defaulting to the "normal" approach when there is no value for `$mainRole`), you can simply create subclasses of the form of:

```
class Admin extends User {
    protected static $mainRole = 'Admin';
}
```

which overrides `$mainRole` with the desired value for `Admin` and inherits the `$mainRole`-logic from `User`. Hence, you can create as many submodels you like this way.